# MvvmCross: Using InvokeOnMainThread in plugin

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am extending the Messenger plugin with functionality, which will make it possible to pass messages on the main thread instead of everything happening on a background thread.

I have extended `BaseSubscription` with a `bool` for knowing that this subscription needs to be messaged on the main thread. Now I need to be able to use `InvokeOnMainThread` from the `TypedInvoke` methods in the actual implementations of the subscriptions.

When I look in the referenced MvvmCross assembly I see that `Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxMainThreadDispatchingObject` contains the `InvokeOnMainThread` method, so the question is how do I get hold of that object so I can invoke the method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to get hold of the UI thread is to inherit from `MvxMainThreadDispatchingObject`

If the hierarchy won't let you, then the next easiest way is to add the `IMvxServiceConsumer` marker interface and to then use the `GetService<T>` extension method:

```
public class MyClass 
   : MyBaseClass
   , IMvxServiceConsumer
{
    // ...

    private bool DoStuff(Action stuff)
    {
        var dispatcherProvider = this.GetService<IMvxMainThreadDispatcherProvider>();
        var dispatcher = dispatcherProvider.Dispatcher;
        if (dispatcher == null) {
           return false;
        }

        return dispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction(action);
    }
 }
```

The `GetService<T>()` static method could also be invoked as a static method if preferred (if you don't want to use `IMvxServiceConsumer`).

---

Notes:

- if you are sharing code between 'Apps' and 'Services'/'BackgroundAgents' you need to be very careful to check for error conditions - there isn't always a UI thread available.
- Android is particularly special - the UI thread can only really be accessed via the current foreground activity - currently MvvmCross tracks this (via Activity OnStart and OnResume hooks) in the `IMvxAndroidCurrentTopActivity` service - but there's no guarantee that you will always have a foreground activity running - e.g. if your code ever loads non-MvvmCross activities then obviously MvvmCross won't know about these.
- You should not hold on to references to the Dispatcher - if you do, then you may be holding Android Activity's in memory beyond their natural lifetimes
- I guess `DoStuff` could be put into an extension method too - perhaps I'll add that in v3 (https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/150)

Comment: Is this still up to date?

Comment: Inheriting from MvxMainThreadDispatchingObject worked a treat for me (in the iOS of one of my MvvmCross plugins).

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to call the DoStuff function? For example, to display a loading sequence. Thanks.